# Product Quanity

Tags: forms, dynamic

I am trying to find the best way to display/change a quantity in a row. Right now it is static, but I would like for them to be able to click "100" then you have the option to change it in that row dynamically. Not a drop down, because they can do custom quantities. Is this possible, does this make sense?

```
<td class="checkout-quantity">100</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do it with CSS, here it is. For those who might want to do the same.

```
.checkout-quantity{
text-align:center;
width:40px;
background-color:transparent;
border:0;
outline:1px solid transparent;
outline-offset: 0!important;
-webkit-transition: all 100ms linear;
-moz-transition: all 100ms linear;
-ms-transition: all 100ms linear;
-o-transition: all 100ms linear;
transition: all 100ms linear;
}


.checkout-quantity:hover, .order-quantity:focus{
background-color:#fff;
outline:1px solid #ccc;
}
```